# How to use one double quote in GraphQL Apollo filters request?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using React with GraphQL Apollo.

But I can't send value with only one double quote.

When I use `value:["""]` or `value:["\""]`, I get an error *GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unterminated string*

I can't use single quotes `value:['"']` - *"Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:22) Unexpected single quote character ('), did you mean to use a double quote (")?*

It's possible to use one double quote with text `""""text"""`. Without text `"""""""` - I have an error.

In GraphiQL it works perfectly `value: ["\"hello"]`.

With variables I can use double quotes but this approach makes everything too difficult.

Is it possible to do it?

Example of my request:

```
{
  items_all(
    page_request: 
    { 
      filter_request: {property: "full_name", value: ["text"], operator: LIKE}) 
    {
    content {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: just use variables, this is the right way for all dynamic query elements .... "too difficult"? good joke ... "works in graphiql" - check request in network tab for details, does it work without text?

Comment: Can you share the code that's around this query? I assume you're just escaping things wrong. I don't know why you're trying to "just add more quotes". The answer usually lies in "adding more backslashes". That being said, the comment above is correct. You should be using variables for this. It's the right way, and it's very simple to do.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I have to use variables. 

"Too difficult" because queries are formed like strings and after that are inserted into queries. I need to rewrite a lot of code in order to use variables.

Comment: Wrong choice ... Who told you to do that? Filters usually are tree shaped **objects** ... **don't use snake_case, use camelCase**, it's a graphQL standard

Comment: @xadm, it was before me :) 

Could you please post your answer? I think developers need to know that you need to use variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would suggest instead of LIKE you can use 'contains'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).